# Detecting "good" exampes of objects in images with Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I need to detect "good" photos of ID cards. I use this as a pre-validation to make sure the user has uploaded a good, fully visible, lit, unobstructed photo of their ID card. I want to reject photocopies, out of focus, partial, handheld, or too far from the camera versions of the ID card.

Originally I was using just Tesseract OCR to extract data from the ID cards. This works reasonably well since it requires a "decent" photo of the ID to be able to extract enough keywords to consider it valid. But it's a very slow process (around 8 seconds per OCR, and I need to rotate the image 90 degrees 3 times so i get all rotations - I can't rely on Tesseract's automatic detection because it fails for an ID card which contains PDF417 or MRZ; this means an ID card detection takes over 30 seconds to process).

So I've used [make_image_classifier](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/tree/master/tensorflow_hub/tools/make_image_classifier) with the images I've been collecting from the previous version and I was able to train a model to find "front" and "back" side photos of ID cards. I'm using [this example script](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/python/label_image.py) to test.

The object detection works, but it's too good. It's able to detect ID cards even if partially covered (even cutting 50% of an ID card photo and it's still detects it correctly with >90% confidence).

- Is it possible to use this trained model and configure the detection to accept only fully visible objects?

  - Alternatively, would it be a good idea to also add to the training set "damaged" images of the positive images? Randomly cropped, blurred, darkened, etc?
- Is it possible to extract the rotation angle of the object being detected?

Originally I tried this with OpenCV and a HAAR cascade, but unfortunately OpenCV requires familiarity with its API, as every author seems to use it slightly different, and examples in a variety of languages. Examples are outdated, no longer run, or the binaries are not included in modern Linux releases - and don't really work at all on Windows.

Comment: It is good idea to add to training data all sorts of images including damaged, randomly cropped ,blurred  and darkened. Since the model will learn form training dataset. it can work well on real time data i.e., test dataset. Use `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` to Generate batches of tensor image data with real-time data augmentation. For more details on the library refer https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator